# Accessing object properties where the property name is in a variable

Tags: javascript, jsobject

I am trying to check if a certain item exists in a JS object. To do this, I need to use whatever ID is passed into my method. At the moment I'm struggling to actually use the variable's value. Here's what I'm doing:

```
data.entries.id
```

So I have my object setup as:

```
var data = { 
  "entries" : { 
  }
};
```

Therefore, the `.id` part will check if a certain ID exists. If it does, I do nothing, if it doesn't, I want to add it. At the moment, by using data.entries.id, every time I simply check if 'id' exists in 'entries' which is not what I want. Let's say my variable value was 'part1' then instead of `data.entries.id` I want it to look for `data.entries.part1`.

So, how do I pass in the variable's value when I check for this, as opposed to the variable name.

I hope that makes sense, and I hope you can help!

Comment: JSON is a data serialization format. Do you mean a JS object?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data.entries[id]; // Where id is a variable`

This notation is to access the property using a variable

Comment: I knew it was something easy that I was overlooking, thanks - just waiting 5 mins for stack overflow to allow me to accept the answer.