# How to configure and lookup enums in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Using this technique to setup enums in javascript, I would now like to search based on some other variable in my function below.

Here's the enum config:

```
var enums_instrumentType = Object.freeze({
    CASH: 0,
    EQUITY: 1,
    COMPOSITE_INDEX:2 ,
    EXCHANGE_RATE:3 ,
    IR_INDEX: 4,
    IR_SWAP_INDEX: 5
});
var enums_tenorUnit = Object.freeze({
      DAY: 0,
      WEEK: 1,
      MONTH: 2,
      YEAR: 3
});

function test(){
   thisInstr = _.findWhere(instrumentsList, { id: mem.instrument_id });  // FIND IT !
   var tenor_unit = thisInstr.ir_index.tenor.unit;     // 0: DAY, 1: WEEK, etc.
   var tenor_size = thisInstr.ir_index.tenor.size;     // number of units

   // HOW TO LOOKUP tenor_unt IN enums_tenorUnit, where tenor_unit is an integer value ???
```

}

thanks in advance...
Bob

Comment: You're looking for the `[ ]` operator.

Comment: [See this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417864/accessing-object-properties-where-the-property-name-is-in-a-variable) (or many others like it).

Comment: i think you have it backwards, it seems like you want to convert a number to a string: ["day","week","month"][1] == "week"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming `tenor_unit` is something like `0` or `1`:

```
var numericValue = _.keys(enums_tenorUnit)[tenor_unit];
```

however, if `tenor_unit` is something like `DAY` or `WEEK` then simply:

```
var numericValue = enums_tenorUnit[tenor_unit];
```

alternatively, if you're looking for a boolean result rather than the literal value and if `tenor_unit` is something like `DAY` or `WEEK` you could use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
var tenorUnitExists = tenor_unit in enums_tenorUnit;
```

Comment: tenor_unit is an integer value, so this worked: var tenorName = _.keys(enums_tenorUnit)[tenor_unit]; (where tenor_unit=0, 'DAY' was returned.

Comment: I have a related questions regarding how I can move those enum defs into an enums.js file. I'm using Durandal framework. Perhaps I'll just post a new questions.

Comment: @bob, I don't have any experience with the Durandal fwk, it is in your best interest to post another question anyway.